# Some process is eating free disk space

Tags: disk-usage, iotop

Some process is continuously eating my free space. Once it dropped to 0 bytes, I freed up some space by deleting few media files, but then it again started to reduce the freed space. I used iotop to findout which process is using disk, and it only shows `init` and nothing else. Following is a screenshot:

[image]

Can anybody help me to fix this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like `htop` instead and it will show you the amount of allocated memory for each process.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install htop
sudo htop
```

Press <kbd>F6</kbd> to choose what to sort the results by.

Also, have you checked to see if something may be incessantly filling up the error logs?

---

**EDIT:**

Because you have identified the culprit is using allotting a lot of space for log-files, you might want to look into using something like `logrotate` to help manage log-files.

Here is an official description:

```
Description-en: Log rotation utility
 The logrotate utility is designed to simplify the administration of
 log files on a system which generates a lot of log files.  Logrotate
 allows for the automatic rotation compression, removal and mailing of
 log files.  Logrotate can be set to handle a log file daily, weekly,
 monthly or when the log file gets to a certain size.  Normally, logrotate
 runs as a daily cron job.
```

Of course, you can also usually change the settings of the application itself to only report errors, to only report warnings and errors, or to fully report everything.

To install logrotate:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install logrotate
```

For more info:

```
man logrotate
```

Comment: I have htop installed and I checked. There are couple of processes running  but could not identify which process consumes free disk space.

Comment: I figured out the problem with the help of `htop` as well. It was something related to one of my applications which run at startup by a script at `/etc/init/` directory. My application continuously writes a log file (which was of 82GB when I identify it). Since the script is invoked by the `init` process, `iotop` shows `init` process as the one who does disk writes. Thanks.